# How to return an HttpResponse(writing and downloading a csv) and redirect to an Html page

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django and i am trying to return, from a view, an **HttpResponse that instantly downloads a csv** on the browser (I've done that already!) and  **redirects the user to a new Html** page.
I've already seen the HttpResponseRedirect however i've not been able to **do both** (download and redirect)

This is part of my views.py file

Views.py

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="filename.csv"'
writer = csv.writer(response)
k=0
for t in text:
    if k==0:
       writer.writerow(['#','text'])
    k+=1
    writer.writerow([k, +str(t[0])])
return response
```

Is there a way that allows me to do both?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to do a GET request to download the file?

Comment: Not yet. I'm new to django so i hope i am not saying something 'stupid' but the csv file is generated with a post request from the user. So, the user send me some information, i work with it and generate new information that i want to pass it to a csv and give it back to the user. Since i am using a POST method to get the user input, i'm not sure if i can do a GET request to download the file.